# How to implement non-blocking infinite loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, asynchronous, python-multithreading, coroutine

I have an infinite loop that reads video frames from webcam and each frame will go through a complex function that requires high computing power. So when displaying the frames the program will feel kinda laggy because of the blocking code.

What I intend to do now is,

- only collect the first few frames when target object appears
- Put them into a separate thread to avoid code blocking.

I've measure the number of frames captured by webcam every second, that is ~28 frames. So every second the while loop will only collect the first 5 frame and process all of them in another thread, and return the result after all 5 functions are completed.

I've tried to use 'Pool' and 'Queue' but couldn't get it to work, the loop still gets blocked. The code below vaguely represents how my program look like now, will edit it when I get home, using phone to post now.

```
def detect(frame):
    # detect target object from images
    pass

def nn(frame):
    # some heavy processing code
    pass

count = 0
stack = []

while True:
    frame = cv2.imread(0)

    detected = detect(frame)

    # stop collecting images when collected 5
    if detected and count <= 5:
        stack.append(frame)
        count += 1

    # start processing
    if len(stack) == 5:
        p = Pool(4)
        results = p.map(nn, frame)
        p.close()
        p.join()

        # reset
        stack = []
        count = 0
```

Am I getting the concept right? Or I need to do something else like coroutine?

Comment: Try using multiprocessing.
Here's a simple example I made using ping (please read my notes in comments about CPU-bound tasks) :
https://gist.github.com/ltpitt/6cdcb5377c462445a315703c5062397c

Comment: I see. I'll update the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using [rq](http://python-rq.org/).
A simple message queue for python.
First, the implementation of the method you need to run asynchronously.

It will run your `nn` function, in this case,
then, set a simple configuration for the message queue,
I use connectionPool from the [redis](https://pypi.org/project/redis/) package.

Basically, you send out the whole task to a parallel process executed by a rq worker.

```
def nn(frame):
    # some heavy processing code
    pass

def asynch_call(frame):
   p = Pool(4)
   results = p.map(nn, frame)
   p.close()
   p.join()

pool = redis.ConnectionPool(
  host=HOST, 
  port=PORT, 
  password=PASS, 
  db=0)

r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)  
q = Queue('nn_queue', connection=r)

count = 0
stack = []

while True:
    frame = cv2.imread(0)

    detected = detect(frame)

    # stop collecting images when collected 5
    if detected and count <= 5:
        stack.append(frame)
        count += 1

    # start processing
    if len(stack) == 5:

        job = q.enqueue(asynch_call, frame, timeout=any_long_timeout )

        if job.status=='queued':
            print("Job submission ok")

            # reset
            stack = []
            count = 0
```

In order to start a worker which will handle the asynchronous calls, you have a couple of options, create your own code for a [Worker](http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/) or just run the following command in a separate terminal:

```
rq worker nn_queue
```

See the command with the queue name used above to send the job.
I hope it helps.

Comment: I fixed a bit the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thank. A bit out of the original question, but what is the difference between the Queue from rq and the Queue from python itself?

Comment: Well, in the overall might be the same. Rq is on top of Redis. Rq can just be a simpler integration with your current design than the pure implementation of the python Queue.

Comment: First of all your answer works great! I've achieved non-blocking code with your implementation. Second, by using Queue, does that mean all my frames will be processed sequentially? If yes, how can I make it faster by parallelise this process?

Comment: you'd still need to use python Queue + Multithreading together. Anyway, have in mind that large amount of thread-shared memory has a lots of problematic situations. As you do it is quite right. Instead, for better speed, run separate processes (parallel) to inject frames in a message queue, and then, a consumer `asynch_call`, extracts frames from the queue and processes them using the multi-thread `p.map(nn, frame)`. Not really far from where you are now.

Comment: @Evhz hi! So for my while loop it times out and stops every 180 seconds. Is there a way to keep the loop going infinitely?Or would I just put something like timeout=5000h. Also, is there a way to kill the current running job in RQ? I've tried using start_registry = StartedJobRegistry(queue=q)
and deleting the jobs in a for loop but it doesnt do the trick